# Is their any relationship between the event-queue and the microtask queue?

Tags: javascript

**My Understanding**

It's been described to me that for asynchronous operations, once they've 'loaded', their return value enters the event-queue.

It's also been described to me that `Promise`s & `.then`s are asynchronous operations and their return values stack up on the micro-task|PromiseJobs queue.

If we define 'front-of-the-queue' as the destination for the result of the first asynchronous operation 'loaded'...

I know the call-stack/macro-task queue has to be empty before the front of the event-queue or micro-task queue is loaded onto it.

---

**My Question**

Is there any relationship between the event-queue and the microtask queue?

---

*Unrelated code-snippet*

```js
const f = () => {
  console.log('1')
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    resolve(2)
  ).then(resolve => console.log(resolve))
}

f()

counter = 0;

for (let index = 0; index < 1000000000; index++) {
    counter = index;
}
console.log(3);
```

Comment: Where have you read about microtasks and macrotasks that did not explain the difference?

Comment: @Bergi Here's what I use: https://javascript.info/event-loop

Comment: "*Immediately after every macrotask, the engine executes all tasks from microtask queue, prior to running any other macrotasks or rendering or anything else.*" is quite clear, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `microtask` queue or `job` queue was introduced in ES6 with the introduction of promises.

> There is no any such relationship but there is a difference ,the event
> queue puts the task  at the back of the queue, behind all the other
> tasks ,while microtask queue puts it in the front and executes the task
> right after the current function in the callstack is executed.

Overall the priority of `microtask` queue > `event` queue (Valid for both **Node js** and **Frontend Javascript**).

More Explaination [here](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-event-loop#es6-job-queue)

Comment: Thanks @Shubh it was a good article. Hope to find more like that. Now can I confirm that the event-queue and the micro-task queue are two separate things - the micro-task queue isn't found in the event-queue or anything like that?

Comment: Yeah right ,these are two different queues designed for different tasks :)